# rospy ImportError - cannot find custom module under src/ folder

Tags: rospy, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. create a new package under ~/catkin_ws/src:

   ```
   catkin_create_pkg foopy rospy
   ```
2. create src/foopy folder and add **init**.py in it
3. create a main.py under scripts/ folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8

import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('foopy')
import rospy

import sys
for f in sys.path:
    print f
```

Then chmod +x and execute it using:

```
rosrun foopy main.py
```

It prints:

```
/home/k/catkin_ws/src/foopy/scripts
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/home/k/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7
...
```

Which does not include module foopy of my src/foopy folder. So when I import anything created under src/foopy/, it will raise an ImportError.

How to solve this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223613/rospy-importerror---cannot-find-custom-module-under-src/-folder/) by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 391 on 2016-01-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> How to solve this issue?

Have you created a `setup.py` and uncommented the `catkin_python_setup()` line of your `CMakeLists.txt`?

See [wiki/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile - Installing scripts and exporting modules](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile#Installing_scripts_and_exporting_modules) and [Catkin 0.6.16 documentation » User Guide » Handling of setup.py](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html).

---

Edit: you also don't mention whether you've rebuilt your workspace before trying to execute your script. Catkin cannot generate the necessary `setup.*` files (that will setup your `PYTHONPATH`) if you don't.

---

Also: `import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('foopy')` is not necessary anymore in Hydro+.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on 2016-01-07**:
Many thanks for your reply! Problem resolved!

**Comment by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on 2016-01-07**:
But it's weird when I am printing out the sys.path, it does not include src path still, but when I import some file under 'src/foopy' using `from foopy import foopkg` it is working. How did python find foopkg.py?

**Comment by [sheaffej](https://answers.ros.org/users/33374/sheaffej/) on 2018-01-21**:
This totally solved my problem, after already having struggled for many hours. I had done everything EXCEPT uncomment catkin_python_setup() in CMakeLists.txt. After doing that, it worked perfectly.